# Trying to create single 0/1 columns from a single column with multiple values for each record

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I have data on issues that have occurred in a production environment. There is a column called Tags which currently has multiple strings for each record. What I have in mind is single 0/1 columns for each unique tag which will allow users to look at a certain type of issues, but I'm struggling to do it. I was using Tableau Prep to prepare the data before I hit this snag. Any guidance on how to do it in Tableau Prep or Excel will be hugely welcome. Thank you so much

E.g. From this

```
<S.No.>         Tags
Incident 1     "arms";"hands";"eyes";
Incident 2     "head";"hands";"arms";
Incident 3     "ear";"eyes";
Incident 4     "hair";
```

To this:

```
<S.No.>         isArms   isHands     isEyes   isHead  isEar  isHair
Incident 1       Yes     Yes         Yes      No      No     No
Incident 2       Yes     Yes         No       Yes     No     No
Incident 3       No      No          Yes      No      Yes    No
Incident 4       No      No          No       No      No     Yes
```

Comment: Your question is very vague.  It would be helpful to see your inputs (example of data) and how you would like to see the output.

Comment: Hey, just added an example of how I'm looking to transform my data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty and I'm looking forward to seeing much more elegant and professional solutions to learn from them but it works in a quick and dirty way (assuming your data is in columns A and B).

```
Sub CleanData()

    Dim objDict As Object
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lng As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    Set objDict = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")


    For Each cll In Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        str = Replace(Left(cll.Value, Len(cll.Value) - 1), """", "")
        arr = Split(str, ";")
        For lng = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not objDict.Contains(CStr(arr(lng))) Then objDict.Add CStr(arr(lng))
        Next
    Next

    Range("C1").Resize(, objDict.Count) = objDict.toarray()

    With ActiveSheet
        lCol = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
        lRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    Range(Range("C2"), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(C$1,$B2)),1,0)"
    Range(Range("C2"), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value = Range(Range("C2"), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value

    For lng = 3 To lCol
        Cells(1, lng).Value = "is" & Application.Proper(Cells(1, lng))
    Next

    Columns(2).Delete

End Sub
```